# thin using high cpu and not replying to request

Tags: ruby, thin

After a timeout occurs on thin, the process keep using high cpu. The only way is to restart it (I let it run more than a day)

this is the output of strace

```
ruby@localhost:~$ strace -p 17830
Process 17830 attached
brk(0x7cf38000)                         = 0x7cf38000
brk(0x7d3ac000)                         = 0x7d3ac000
brk(0x7d655000)                         = 0x7d655000
brk(0x7de8c000)                         = 0x7de8c000
brk(0x7e616000)                         = 0x7e616000
brk(0x7a0c9000)                         = 0x7a0c9000
.. and one similar line each 3 - 4 seconds
```

Why this happen? I've seen this also on mongrel. Why if the http request already ended it keeps up?

Comment: not enough information. Can you post a stacktrace using the method given here: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/9/22/inspecting-a-live-ruby-process.html

Comment: i tried all methods with gdb and after I enter any command which call gdb dont reply. just give a blank line. I tested with other process and it worked. but not with the dead one.